# Writing search APIs based on different combination of search params in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api

I have developed following three APIs for my spring-boot application:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/state-transitions/searchWithFromState")
  public ResponseEntity<List<TcStateTransitionDTO>>
      searchWithFromState(
      @RequestParam(value = "fromStateId") String fromStateId) {
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok(stateTransitionService.findByFromState(fromStateId));
  }

  
  @GetMapping(value = "/state-transitions/searchWithFromStateAndToState")
  public ResponseEntity<List<TcStateTransitionDTO>>
      searchWithFromStateAndToState(
      @RequestParam(value = "fromStateId") String fromStateId,
      @RequestParam(value = "toStateId") String toStateId) {
   
    return ResponseEntity.ok(stateTransitionService
        .findByFromStateAndToState(fromStateId, toStateId));
  }

  
  @GetMapping(value = "/state-transitions/searchWithFromStateAndAction")
  public ResponseEntity<List<TcStateTransitionDTO>>
      searchWithFromStateAndAction(
      @RequestParam(value = "fromStateId") String fromStateId,
      @RequestParam(value = "actionId") String actionId) {
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok(stateTransitionService
        .findByFromStateAndAction(fromStateId, actionId));
  }
```

These APIs are working perfectly. But I am wondering if is there any way to write these APIs in a better fashion. I am thinking this because, if say, there are n params to search, in this way, I will end up in write 2^n-1 number of APIs.

Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive variable number of parameters if you receive them as a `Map<String,Object>` form like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/search")
public ResponseEntity<Page<TcStateTransitionDTO>> search(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> params) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(stateTransitionService.searchByParams(params));
}
```

You can create a criteria map and generate dynamic query based on the parameters using [criteriaBuilder](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/criteria/CriteriaBuilder#:%7E:text=Interface%20CriteriaBuilder%20Used%20to%20construct%20criteria%20queries%2C%20compound,that%20Java%20generics%20are%20not%20compatible%20with%20varags.). If you're using JPA, then just pass the specification generated through criteriabuilder to the findAll method.

```
public Page<TcStateTransitionDTO> searchByParams(Map<String, Object> params) {
    PageRequest pageRequest = generatePageRequestFromParams(params);
    Specifications specifications = getSearchSpecifications(params);
    return repository.findAll(specifications, pageRequest);
}
```

This `getSpecification(Map<String, Object> params)` method that I've mentioned is the main gameplayer here. The main trick is to write this method efficiently. I would suggest to read the above link to know more about CriteriaBuilder and do a bit study on specifications.